# Does __destruct run by itslef or do I need to use unset() or register_shutdown_function() in order for it to work

Tags: php, oop, destructor, php-7, magic-methods

a) Does __destruct run every single time a code is processed, just by itself

b) Or, no, you need to use unset($objectName) in order for it to run (another option is register_shutdown_function() ).

c) Are there any other aspects related to this? Like it works by itself when this or that, and you can also use this or that in order for it to run, anything...

Comment: I tested this with a code without unset() and it runs by itself (like it would echo some text).

Comment: Somebody told me this - __destruct() is only called when you unset(), it is not executed when the script ends.There is another way to have a destructor executed at the end of the script automatically (without calling unset()). Check out register_shutdown_function()

Comment: And this is a video about it, the one that made me wonder about how this works - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xeKc5VGUkPM ; Like he says there, ok we will trigger __destruct so the object can be deleted.

Comment: Check the highest scored answer in the dupe, instead of the accepted answer.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the video. He is prematurely deleting the object with unset. Whenever the object is destroyed the destructor will be called automatically. Objects are always freed up when the script is finished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the `unset()` function is not the only way to call `__destruct()`. According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), “the destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence”.

To illustrate this, consider the following methods when `__destruct()` will be called **automatically**:

1) It is called instantly when the class instance is not assigned to any variable:

```
<?php
new TheClass(); #-> this line calls __destruct()

/* More PHP Code */
?>
```

2) It is called when script execution is stopped:

```
<?php
$obj = new TheClass();
exit; #-> this line calls __destruct()

/* More PHP Code */
?>
```

3) It is called when `unset()` destroys the reference of the class:

```
<?php
$obj = new TheClass();
unset($obj); #-> this line calls __destruct()

/* More PHP Code */
?>
```

4) It is called when the value of variable is reassigned:

```
<?php
$obj = new TheClass();
$obj = 'any value'; #-> this line calls __destruct()

/* More PHP Code */
?>
```

5) It is called when the script completes its execution:

```
<?php
$obj = new TheClass();

/* More PHP Code */

#-> this line calls __destruct()
?>
```

6) It is called when exiting variable scope:

```
<?php
call_user_func(function() {
    $obj = new TheClass();

    /* More PHP Code */

    return true; #-> this line calls __destruct()
});

/* More PHP Code */
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. So the __destruct can be seen as something like an entry point for the deletion. A situation when an object needs to be deleted (any) -> I will go to __destruct, run what is there and then it will get deleted. So __destruct is like a "door" (entry point) for any type of deletion (so nothing else in an object code gets read - it just goes to __destruct, runs what is there and it gets deleted).